# How can I click on styled input in Selenium when underlying input is hidden without relying on implementation detail

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have a radio button in which the underlying input is hidden but still exists for accessibility (FYI I'm using [antd](https://ant.design/components/radio) - UI)

I want to click on the radio button in Selenium but don't want to rely on implementation detail attributes like `ant-radio` (antd class name - UI library) or DOM structure like parent of it as it make the tests more fragile to implementation detail changes,

Selecting the input with `data-test-id` is great but I cannot click on it as it's hidden:

This is the Automation code:

```java
ExpectedConditions::elementToBeClickable.apply(
  By.cssSelector("[data-test-id='my-input']")
)
  .apply(driver)
  .click();
```

Underlying, `elementToBeClickable` required the element to be visible: (`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`)

**I don't wanna use JS to solve this**

**This is the radio button:**

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.ant-radio-wrapper');
const radioButton = document.querySelector('.ant-radio');
const underlyingInput = document.querySelector('input');


wrapper.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  radioButton.classList.toggle("ant-radio-checked");
  const shouldBeChecked = radioButton.classList.contains('ant-radio-checked');
  underlyingInput.checked = shouldBeChecked;
});
```

```css
/* From here - styles to make pretty radio button */

.ant-radio-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.88);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5714285714285714;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ant-radio-wrapper .ant-radio {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.88);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5714285714285714;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ant-radio-wrapper .ant-radio-input {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.ant-radio-wrapper .ant-radio-inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  inset-block-start: 0;
  inset-inline-start: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.ant-radio-wrapper .ant-radio-inner::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  inset-block-start: 50%;
  inset-inline-start: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-block-start: -8px;
  margin-inline-start: -8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-block-start: 0;
  border-inline-start: 0;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.78, 0.14, 0.15, 0.86);
  content: "";
}

.ant-radio-wrapper::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: "\a0";
}

.ant-radio-wrapper .ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner {
  border-color: #1677ff;
  background-color: #1677ff;
}

.ant-radio-wrapper .ant-radio-checked::after {
  position: absolute;
  inset-block-start: 0;
  inset-inline-start: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #1677ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  content: "";
}

.ant-radio-wrapper .ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner::after {
  transform: scale(0.375);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.78, 0.14, 0.15, 0.86);
}


/* From here - Styles to make it less ugly */

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Noto Sans', sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 70px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Click the radio button</h1>
  <label id="wrapper" class="ant-radio-wrapper">
    <span class="ant-radio ant-wave-target">
      <input type="radio" class="ant-radio-input" data-test-id="my-input">
      <span class="ant-radio-inner"></span>   
     </span>
   </label>
</div>

<br>
<footer>Styles and DOM structure extracted from antd</footer>
```

[Link to the same snippet in CodePen](https://codepen.io/raz-luvaton/pen/eYxYard)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptExecutor to click on it

```
public void clickOnElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```

You can try in browser console with css selector

```
$$("input[data-test-id='my-input']")[0].click()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to write it, I don't wanna use JavaScript

Comment: I guess you are missing input tag. Have you ever tried  input[data-test-id='my-input']?

Comment: I have an input tag as you can see in the code

Comment: The locator you're chosing is hidden by span tag. Use span locator. with xpath: //span[contains(@class,'ant-radio')], cssselector: span[class *= 'ant-radio ant']. Your code will be something like this:

Comment: Note: please check if the locator is in iframe. Switch to iframe before clicking on radio button.